# アラートダイアログのタイトルを非表示にしたい

Tags: onsen-ui

画像の赤丸で囲った部分を非表示にする方法はありますでしょうか？

[image]

Comment: どのように実装していますか？実装しているコードも記載してください。

Answer (score 0):

単純に[公式ドキュメント](https://ja.onsen.io/v2/api/js/ons-alert-dialog.html)に記載しているサンプル上で説明するなら
`templete`の`class="alert-dialog-title"`の`DIV`を消せばいいと思います。